# SQL Server having a column as both PK and FK

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key-relationship

I have not done much database design work and I was searching around for some example.
While I know the difference from a primary and foreign key,  one thing that caught be off guard was that even if a Table has a primary key and is used as a foreign key in another table, as I was used the GUI SSMS tools, I noticed that I sometime end up having this

```
PhoneID (PK, int, not null)
```

While my User table

```
UserId(PK,FK, int, not null)
```

BOTH of these tables have these ID's as primary keys in those tables, along with foreign keys in other tables, but why does one of them have  "PK,FK"   obviously I accidentally created it, but should it be like that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Possible for a Primary key to be a Foreign Key as well at the same time.

But looking at you database design, In your case I dont think it was intentional it was done by mistake. And if it wasnt done by mistake then you need to fix it.

In your `dbo.PhoneType` Table the column `PhoneTypeID`  needs to be a Primary key only not a Foreign key.  My guess is this was done by mistake, you wanted to create a Foreign key in your `dbo.Phone` table on column `PhoneTypeID` referencing `PhoneTypeID` column in `dbo.PhoneType` table. But somehow you end up create a foreign key constraint on the Primary key column of the dbo.Phontype table.

This Design contradicts constraints.

In simple english :  The foreign Key Constraint on your `dbo.PhoneType(PhoneTypeID)` enforces that you cannot have a PhoneTypeID in dbo.PhoneType table unless it exists in PhoneTypeID column of dbo.Phone table.

On the other hand Foreign Key Constraint on `dbo.Phone(PhoneTypeID)` enforces that you cannot have a PhoneTypeID in dbo.Phone unless it exists in dbo.PhoneType(PhoneTypeID).

and same is true for the UserID column in dbo.Users table.

**Solution**

> You need to drop the following Constraints to make it work properly.
>
> 1) In dbo.PhoneType table Drop Foreign key constraint referencing
>   PhoneTypeID column in dbo.phone table.
>
> 2) In dbo.Users Table drop the Drop Foreign key constraint referencing
>   UserID column in dbo.phone table.

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible, yes. A primary key of a table could also be a foreign key referencing another table.

In your case, I'm not exactly sure what you did. You can check the constraints to see which column the `UserId` column is referencing.

As an additional note, simply adding a foreign reference to a table does not implicitly make that column a foreign key on another table. For example, just because you add `FK_PhoneTypeID` to the `Phone` table, SQL Server **does not** automatically make `PhoneTypeID` column in the `PhoneType` table a FK. In your statements, somewhere, it's possible that you made assignments to other columns, or even to themselves.